# Tips & trix for importing odd CSV files into python

Tags: python, csv

*EDIT: A solution was supplied by @CoryKramer. Odd CSV files (which can be easily modified by opening them as TXT files) can be manipulated by the [PyParsing](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module.*

ORIGINAL QUESTION: A common problem I have encountered as a research student is that many of our analysis machines produce data in the form of odd CSV files that are not strictly comma-separated. This makes it cumbersome to import the data into other programs for running analysis and statistics. I have previously imported this data into Excel but it takes time and I will use Python for final data analysis. This requires hundreds of delete or copy-and-past maneuvers which may result in important data being accidentally lost as the classic Excel Text Import Wizard have problems with importing these files.

My goal is to develop a Python script that can extract data from these odd CSV file. I have beginners understanding of Python from tutorials using Jupyter Notebook (https://jupyter.org/).

I have attached [a link](http://shorturl.at/bcpAG) to an example of one of the data files I am working with, as well as [a screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYf9S.jpg).

Essentially, I need to remove everything that is part of the "header" (denoted '#'). Then follows a set of named objects (*MT1, MT2 ... etc.*) were I am interested in the values associated with *'points'* and *'lenght'*.

Any help on how to approach this is greatly appreciated!

Below I have provided an example of the original code from one of the CSV files, and secondly an example of how I aim to have it sorted.

**(1) Data datafile1 before sorting**

```
# MODEL datafile1.mod
# NAME  IMOD-NewModel
# PIX SCALE:  x = 1
#             y = 1
#             z = 1
# PIX SIZE      = 915
# UNITS: pm
# Model to Image index coords:
#      SCALE  = ( 1, 1, 1)
#      OFFSET = ( 0, 0, 0)
#      ANGLES = ( 0, 0, 0)


OBJECT 1
NAME:  MT1(Splayingprofile1)
       5 contours
       object uses open contours.
       color (red, green, blue) = (0, 1, 0)

    CONTOUR #1,1,0  2 points    length = 2.08382e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #2,1,0  3 points    length = 3.47985e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #3,1,0  3 points    length = 3.53698e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #4,1,0  3 points    length = 3.53232e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #5,1,0  2 points    length = 2.10433e+006 pm

OBJECT 2
NAME:  MT2(Splayingprofile1)
       5 contours
       object uses open contours.
       color (red, green, blue) = (0, 1, 1)

    CONTOUR #1,2,0  4 points    length = 3.11604e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #2,2,0  3 points    length = 3.09011e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #3,2,0  3 points    length = 2.91269e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #4,2,0  3 points    length = 3.02468e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #5,2,0  3 points    length = 2.8044e+006 pm

OBJECT 3
NAME:  MT3(Splayingprofile1)
       3 contours
       object uses open contours.
       color (red, green, blue) = (1, 0, 1)

    CONTOUR #1,3,0  3 points    length = 3.02827e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #2,3,0  4 points    length = 3.87217e+006 pm
    CONTOUR #3,3,0  4 points    length = 3.83487e+006 pm
```

**(2) Data from datafile1 after sorting**

```
Object,Splaying Profile,Curvature Points,Length (pm)
MT1,1,2,2083820
MT1,1,3,3479850
MT1,1,3,3536980
MT1,1,3,3532320
MT1,1,2,2104330
MT2,1,4,3116040
MT2,1,3,3090110
MT2,1,3,2912690
MT2,1,3,3024680
MT2,1,3,2804400
MT3,1,3,3028270
MT3,1,4,3872170
MT3,1,4,3834870
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that example is not a csv file. A csv file generally has one or more lines of header, then *strictly* rows of (possibly comma, or otherwise) delimited values.

Comment: Yes, I thought so to! Do you think it is misleading to tag this as CSV? This is the file we receive from the program I am using when exporting as CSV (IMOD - https://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/). I think part of the problem is that each "object" that could be used as a header has several possible columns associated with it (eg. contour, coordinates, points, lenght).

Comment: Since your example file *does* have a regular, parseable format (just not csv), I think you'll get better traction using something like [PyParsing](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), see [this example](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Reading_Custom_Text_Files_with_Pyparsing.html)

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at the link you provided.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include your code and your problem with your code. Screen captures and code links don't work for many of us.

Comment: I have now included an example of my original code and how it is supposed to be sorted.